# How do I move my blender models (made from a single model) to the 0.0.0 zone on the axis

Tags: modeling, transforms

My model (well, models) is a bit off on X axis(the red one). How do I move the model so its perfectly centered (its mirrored and/or symmetrical, aside one object(car mirror))?

The reason I need to do this is because I am re modeling the cars taillights to look more realistic, and by adding a new mesh and mirroring it, its really hard to place them exactly on right distance and right area on the car rear panel...

[image: location]

[image]

My reddit username is Gatemaster2000

Reddit post crosspost archive link: http://archive.is/ZqY1c

Comment: What is the reason to add the reddit username here?

Comment: I crossposted it to r/blenderhelp/

Comment: This isn't related to the question. In general make sure to provide as much information as possible in post here, then there's no need to add links to your profiles elsewhere. Links to 3-rd party sites / profiles (with some exceptions) are discouraged here mainly because they tend to become unusable.

Comment: Okay, i added archive link of the reddit post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thing like your problem:

[image]

**Shift + S** and select, **Selection to cursor** (Be sure to use it in Object mode)
[image]

It will moved to center as on your 3d cursor. (if your 3d cursor is not in center already try **Shift + S** and select, **Cursor to center**)

[image]

Now you may adjust the location of your model along z axis manually, I hope it will not difficult for you.

Best of luck!

Updated:
You may try to hit Ctrl + A and apply location and also please follow the steps as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I tried it. Sadly it dosent seem to work.... What happens is that only single part gets put to the center, instead of all of the parts/submodels of the main model.... Any fix for it?

Comment: You may select all parts and hit Ctr + J to combined all parts before using the above solution, later you may select any part by hover over on it and hit L key, and hit p key to separate it

Comment: I tried to do that but it dosent seem to properly center it(the little orange dot thingy that seems to be cars centre point? is offset to one side, and if i try to move it this way, the whole model still gets offset on the X axis. How do i make the orange dot to go in the center of the car?

Comment: Please have a look at the updates

Comment: I will try updated version tomorrow!

Comment: I think i will have to manually still assemble the model("Geometry to origin" point for all parts is in the same spot), but thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome, you may vote up answer,  thanks for accepting answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The location of an object is known as it's [origin](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/origin.html). This is the point in 3D space that defines an object's location and you can change it's position in relation to the object's mesh data. This is also the zero point used by the mirroring tools and is often used by the mirror modifier.

While you can move the mesh data in edit mode, more precise options are preferred. The simplest [Set Origin](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/origin.html#set-origin) option would be *Origin to Geometry*, which moves the origin to be in the middle of the existing geometry.

The Set Origin options can be found in the *Object->Tranform* menu, or from the (long) shortcut <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

To have more control, you can use the [3D cursor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html?highlight=snapping) to define the position you want to use. By selecting some existing vertices you can [snap the cursor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#snap-menu) <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to the middle of the selection and then set the origin to the 3D cursor.

[image: set origin]

Comment: suggested edit for your first paragraph.  The location of an objects [local coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_coordinates) point (0, 0, 0) is its [origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system#Number_line) All object data is relative to the origin.